# How to signal CompletableFutures as completed or cancelled from within threads that are associated to them?

Tags: multithreading, java-8, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I've been reading a lot about CompletableFutures, and they focus on the fact that a CompletableFuture has no access over the underlying computation code as Future does. So, how can you signal complete() or cancel() (or check isCancelled(), if you want to interrupt computation from outside) from within any task for which the completableFuture is associated?

EDIT: One of the things that confuses me is that CF are used over the alternatives for either its composability or either its manual settability, which seem to me pretty orthogonal provided the implementation, like in:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { 
                              if(myCondition) CF_REF?.complete();
                              else            CF_REF?.exceptionally();
                           }).thenApply(() -> {
                                        if (myOtherCondition) CF_REF_2?.complete();
 (...)
```

What's the point of designing it ina way that is not "completable"+"composable" at the same time?

I would like to find a way to use them as if CF had used as input an interface similar to an hypothethical CompletableCallable, but don't know how. Something like `Function<CompletableFuture,T>` instead of Callables/Runnables, so we could use it as:

```
CompletableFuture CF_REF_BIS = CompletableFuture.runAsync((CF_REF) -> { 
                                  if(myCondition) CF_REF.complete();
                                  else CF_REF.exceptionally();
                               });

CF_REF_BIS.thenApply(...)
```

When code were going to be computed, the very CF_REF_BIS reference would be returned by the internal execution mechanics as the one actually passed as CF_REF in the future computation, without the need to access it accross scopes.

That would mean we can reuse an de-anonymize the computation code
 simply by creating new CompeltableCallable() and then submiting n times anywhere, where any thread has access to the CompletableFuture semaphore

For instance:

```
CompletableFuture CF_REF = CompletableFuture.runAsync(myCompletableCallable)
             .thenApply(myCompletableCallable) //again
             .thenApply(anotherCompletableCallable);
```

Is there a way to acccomplish that need? Am I forgetting something? Is there any fundamental inconsistency on my approach? Is Java CompletableFuture still in a half-way convenient design?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the javadoc:

[`CompletableFuture#complete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#complete-T-)

> If not already completed, sets the value returned by `get()` and related
>   methods to the given value.

[`CompletableFuture#cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-)

> If not already completed, completes this `CompletableFuture` with a
>   `CancellationException`. Dependent `CompletableFuture`s that have not
>   already completed will also complete exceptionally, with a
>   `CompletionException` caused by this `CancellationException`.
>
> [...]
>
> Parameters:
>
> **mayInterruptIfRunning** - this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

`CompletableFuture` objects are completely unrelated to any threads that may have reachable references to them. In other words, these objects are not meant to signal threads. This type of future is basically a holder for a result with the option to register listeners.

All behavior of `whenXyz` and `thenAbc` is registered with the `CompletableFuture` object. When that behavior executes depends on a number of things: which thread completed (either successfully or exceptionally) the future, whether continuations were registered with the `*Async` methods, etc. This is laid out in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

---

For example, you create a `CompletableFuture` and hand it off to some threads. Presumably, one of these threads will `complete` it. This has no effect on the other threads. They still continue doing exactly what they were doing or trying to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> promise = new CompletableFuture<>();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Runnable action = () -> {
        if (promise.complete("done")) {
            System.out.println("completed by " + Thread.currentThread());
        } else {
            System.out.println("somebody got there first");
        }
    };
    executorService.submit(action);
    executorService.submit(action);
    executorService.submit(action);

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println(promise.get());
}
```

Comment: 1) Wow, I did not assume you can refer to the promise var in the main thread like that, taking into account that the referer code is going to be executed in a separated thread. 2) Every other example I read, uses CompletableFutures by means of supply/runAsync, how would you do the trick referring to the very own promise in the callable code during their very instantiation?. 3) If you don't use lambdas, do you need to pass the CF in constructor of the callable/runnable task as a simple semaphore for each thread? Whats so big about it then so people says it is the Scala way to go, over Futures?

Comment: With `supplyAsync` and `runAsync`, you get back a `CompletableFuture`. It's not necessarily completed yet. You can still hand it off to another thread and have that thread complete it. You can pass the future in any way that is appropriate: constructor argument, local variable capture, etc. I don't know what you mean by _a simple semaphore_.

Comment: I believe Scala has `Future` and `Promise`. Java's `CompletableFuture` is a combination of the two.

Comment: @Whimusical: if you only use `runAsync` and `supplyAsync`, there is no difference to invoke `submit` on an `ExecutorService`, getting a `Future`. So the main difference between `CompletableFuture` and `Future` is already suggested by its name, you *can complete* it explicitly, as shown in this answer. Whether this has anything do do with “Scala’s way of doing it”, I don’t know (and don’t care). It will be useful for certain tasks, but I won’t rewrite all my concurrency related code to now use `CompletableFuture`…